# Rotated picture is not displayed in flask

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

The original pictures are uploaded and store in a directory, after it it displayed in a html page. the route is

```
@mod.route('/profile', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def profile():
    form = UpdateProfileForm()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form.username.data = current_user.username
        form.country.data = Paises.query.all()
        form.telephone.data = current_user.telephone
    image_file = url_for('static', filename='profile_pics/' + current_user.image_file)
    return render_template('profile.html', form=form, image_file=image_file)
```

it display the picture in the webpage when a button for turning 90 degrees reside. the picture below shows the picture in directory too

[image]

The button for turning the picture call the route and function is

```
    path = 'static/profile_pics/'+filename
    i = Image.open(path)
    y, z = i.size
    i2 = i.rotate(90, expand=1)
    i2.save(path)
```

The problem is while in file explorer the picture is properly turn it, in flask webpage it still loading as original.

[image]

thanks for your help with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you restart the Flask app? Clearing your browser's cache could also work.